# With Mojolicious, how do I tell if I am receiving a file directly or via a form?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Using Mojolicious, how can I tell on the server side if a request was made like this:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "@/home/me/some/file.jpg" \
  http://127.0.0.1:3000/tasks/some_task
```

or like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -F "userid=1" \
  -F "filecomment=This is an image file" \
  -F "image=@/home/me/some/filejpg" \
  http://127.0.0.1:3000/tasks/some_task
```

How can I identify differences - I suppose on the `Mojo::Request` object?

Comment: @ikegami thanks - but this is not about how do I _send_ a request in the different ways, it's about how do I tell the difference on the server/receiving end- Edited accordingly for clarity

Comment: For the request see [here](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Message/Request). You can access the parameters of your second request with `$req->param(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really because the first request makes no sense. It doesn't send a form, but it sends a `Content-Type` header identifying the content as form data.

The first request should use something like the following:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
```

That would allow the server to distinguish based on content type. A form will have a Content-Type `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead.